# Overpass Turbo query within visible area (without using OSM script style)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, bbox

I'm trying to do really basic queries on the current visible area in the Overpass UI, and I'd like to know what is the equivalent of 'bbox' in the following format:

```
(
  way["waterway"](53.3,-3.1,53.5,-2.6);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I'd like to replace the **(53.3,-3.1,53.5,-2.6)** with the equivalent of **bbox**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! I was just hacking about trying different things...

```
(
  way["waterway"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```